# Error when running commands inside git submodule from Thor task

Tags: ruby, shell, cucumber, thor

I have a Rails 3.2 project that is a git repo and inside the `vendor/autotest-new` directory I have a git submodule.

I want to use Thor to automate some actions. For example I need to perform
`cucumber -d -f json > test.json` inside the git submodule.

Manually it works fine, but when I run the thor task it throws an error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': cucumber is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails32/bin/cucumber:22:in `<main>'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails32/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails32/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I've already run `bundle install` inside the submodule.

The thor task is:

```
class DB < Thor

  include Thor::Actions

  desc 'test_task',  "test task"
  def test_task
    Dir.chdir("vendor/autotest-new") do
      puts `bundle exec cucumber -d -f json > test.json`
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried

```
run "bundle exec cucumber -d -f json > test.json"
system "bundle exec cucumber -d -f json > test.json"
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Thor, it's bundler.

Answer is here https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1579

I need to use execute that commands in the block

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  #my commands
end
```